# testng mock method return value

Tags: java, mockito

i have the following code

```
private EditAttribute editAttr;
@Mock
private EditAttributeService editAttrServ;

@Mock
private EditAttributeDAO editAttributeDAO;

@DataProvider(name = "getNamesValues")
public Object[][] createData1() {
 return new Object[][] {
   { new EditAttribute.Builder().bioId("abc").sheetId("12e").fid("9BD2B75E-3B00-11DF-B7E4-005056A3157F").context("[{\"id\": 'B8031714-F23B-11DF-8F44-005056A3157F_C4B10A72-F25C-11DF-8F44-005056A3157F',\"value\": \"123\"},{\"id\": '4AB3CB04-2527-11DF-994B-005056A3157F_00CA7BCA-3B9B-11DF-B7E4-005056A3157F' ,\"value\": \"12322\"}]").target("").value("").build() }

 };
}

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    editAttrServ = new EditAttributeService();
}


@Test(dataProvider ="getNamesValues")
public void TestselectAttributes(EditAttribute editAttribute){
    LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedList<String>> queryRes=new LinkedHashMap<String,LinkedList<String>>();
    LinkedList<String> columnsnames=new LinkedList<String>();
    columnsnames.add("city");
    queryRes.put("ColumnName",columnsnames);
    LinkedList<String> tableName=new LinkedList<String>();
    tableName.add("Dim_Plant");
    queryRes.put("TableName",tableName);
    System.out.println("queryRes="+queryRes.size());
    Mockito.when(editAttributeDAO.getNames("", "", "", "", "")).thenReturn(queryRes);

    Assert.assertEquals( editAttrServ.selectAttribute(editAttribute,"","").size(),2);
}
```

The method editAttributeDAO.getNames("", "", "", "", "") does a call to the DAO class method. I am expecting this method not to be executed since i used mockito when and define return value.However is seems to fail and the method is getting called. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: BeforeClass usually expects the setUp method to be static and reference to 'this' is not really something expected there.  Try Before  (BeforeClass usually throws an exception if you try to annotate a non static member, but I am using Mockito 2.0.2-beta).  See: http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/package-summary.html

Comment: Are `EditAttributeDAO` and `EditAttributeDAO.getNames` public, non-static, and non-final?

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding your test. The first 9 lines all seem to be part of the setup of your test. I therefore assume that "selectAttribute" is the business method that you are testing. However, your code is calling that method on a mocked object too. Is EditAttributeService an interface or a class? If it's an interface then Mockito will have mocked the selectAttribute method for you and return an empty collection. If it's a class, it will execute the existing method but you haven't told the mocked editAttributeService how it is linked to the "editAttributesDAO" and that is likely why it is not using the results that you set up at the start of your test method.